# Display Facebook like button in overlay DIV - once, on 2nd page view, for 20 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to display Facebook's like button in an overlay div (page bottom), but there are some additional requests that make it complicated.

1. Visitor would see it when they generate a 2nd page view (they come to the website and opet at least one more page)
2. It should appear only once
3. It should be displayed only for some 20 seconds (or any other number of seconds) or until you click "x" button
4. There would be a short text in front of it (Welcome to Example.com...). Ideally everything would be in this code, without additional DIVs pulled from the page.

I have managed to create a close button. This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#closebutton').click(function(){
        $('#facebookdiv').remove();
        $(this).remove();
        document.cookie="removeit=yes";
    });    
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
      x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
      y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
      x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x=="removeit")
       {
        $('#facebookdiv').remove();
        $('#closebutton').remove();
        }
      }
});
```

Can this and how be achieved? Here is a jsFiddle with some code I'm experimenting with:
http://jsfiddle.net/tj8N6/3/

Thank you in advance!

EDIT

My current code in testing HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$.cookie('fbbox', '1', { path: '/', domain: 'www.example.com' });

if($.cookie('fbbox') == null) { 
    $.cookie('fbbox', '1', {expires:7, path:'/'});
}

if($.cookie('fbbox') == 1) { 
    $.cookie('fbbox', '2', {expires:7, path:'/'});
}

});

var buttonShowTime=20000;
if (fbbox == '2') {
    $('#facebookdiv').show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#facebookdiv').hide();

    }, buttonShowTime);

}
</script>


</head>

<body> 

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div id="facebookdiv">
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/stackoverflowpage" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-colorscheme="dark" data-font="arial"></div>
<div id="closebutton">X</div>
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an incremental cookie starting at 1, if value =2 show the button.

To hide the button use `setTimeout()`

```
/* set time for button to show*/
var buttonShowTime=20000;
if (cookieVal == '2') {
    $('#buttonElemnt').show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#buttonElemnt').hide();

    }, buttonShowTime);

}
```

The rest would be done in html. Create a close button and apply a click handler for same.

```
$('#faceBookClose').click(function(){
     $('#buttonElemnt').hide();
});
```

If the button is already hidden by user, the call to hide it again in `setTimeout()` will not cause any problems

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the fiddle, could you check it? http://jsfiddle.net/tj8N6/6/

Comment: I made up the variable name `cookieVal`. You will need to create cookie functionality. Also, would hide the Facebook with css...and only show it when needed

Comment: Could "ARRcookies" above "cookieVal" be used to create cookies? I suppose that it can be mixed somehow, but I don't know javascript well enough to combine it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I assumed you already had some cookie generating code, or you wouldn't need the code shown to read the cookies. Take a look at jQuery cookie plugin, could simplify what you have and add new

Comment: I'm using Drupal, so the cookie does get generated. This code worked well, but it enables me only to close the button, so I need to mix it somehow with your code to display it only for 20 seconds and only on 2nd page view. If it's much easier, I could use the 1st page view too.

Comment: OK... could ignore the original cookie code you have and create a new cookie. There are lots of cookie tutorials around. A little bit of research would get you going in no time. I assume ou understand my concept about incrementing the cookie.

Comment: Then I'll try to find some, hopefully with explanation how to pull page views.

Comment: cookit code would run every time page loads... = page view. First you would check if your cookie exists( first page view it won't). You create cookie first time with value=1. Next time, you get the value and add 1. If value is 2, show button

Comment: I have updated my code and put it in the HTML page to test it. However, FB like button doesn't show up now and I'm not sure is the code for cookies good.